# I want to swap the value from nested list

Tags: c#

I am writing a program where I need to swap values from nested list.
Here is what I am looking for example:

Let's say I have a `List<object[]>` where these list contains two rows as below:

> {"id1", "id2", "id3"}, {1,2,3}

Now I want to make it like below:

> {"id1", 1}, {"id2", 2}, {"id3", 3}

How can I do that in C#?
Hopefully I have cleared my point.

Comment: Please show us what you've already tried.

Answer (score 3):

With 2 input sequences, this can be treated as a "zip" operation:

```
List<object[]> list = new List<object[]>
{
    new object[] {"id1", "id2", "id3" },
    new object[] {1,2,3},
};
var rotated = Enumerable.Zip(list[0], list[1],
    (x, y) => new object[] { x, y }).ToList();
```

Note I would advise against using lots of `object[]` etc here. There's almost always a better way to represent the data.

---

With an arbitrary number of input sequences, this would need to be done as a "transpose" operation.

Comment: This is applicable to two rows only but let's say I am having more rows. It's unknown piece actually.

Comment: @Jaydeep so you're looking for a "transpose" method?

Comment: Yes I believe that's what I want to do.

Comment: @Jaydeep it is much easier with rectangular data; `List<object[]>` is jagged - meaning: there's no guarantee that each inner item is the same length, but ultimately it isn't very different: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29483660/how-to-transpose-matrix, https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4456420/transpose-2d-array-that-exists-as-ienumerable-of-ienumerable https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1599542/transpose-a-collection etc

Comment: Thank you Marc, 
I believe below post is more useful(specially first answer)
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39484996/rotate-transposing-a-listliststring-using-linq-c-sharp